# Place value notation in quantum computing?

Tags: binary, numbers, computation, quantum-computing

How do quantum computers store numbers in place value systems? Do they use the binary system, like traditional computation does?

Comment: You might get better results on [quantum computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It can do more than binary number in classic computer. 2 qubits can have 4 values. For classic, 2 bits, can store 2 values only